# Elasticsearch SQL query in Canvas : it doesn't work like SQL?

Tags: elasticsearch, canvas, kibana, elasticsearch-sql

I begin to work with the *Canvas* section in *Kibana* - and to retrieve data, it uses **Elasticsearch SQL**.

What I try to do is to retrieve the count of several values ; and I need to group certain values together - the ones that start with the same letters.

**My SQL query looks like this :**

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logs WHERE status LIKE 'missingValue%'),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logs WHERE status LIKE 'errorValue%'),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logs WHERE status='exactErrorValue'),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logs WHERE status='anotherExactErrorValue')
```

When I test this query, [using SQL and a little database, it works](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/12T5)

Now, I want to make this work inside an element of my canvas. I choose a *horizontal bar chart* to represent it.

**This is my elasticsearch SQL query :**

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "monitoring-func-*" 
WHERE status LIKE 'missingValue%'),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "monitoring-func-*"
WHERE status LIKE 'errorValue%'),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "monitoring-func-*" 
WHERE status='exactErrorValue'),
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "monitoring-func-*" 
WHERE status='anotherExactErrorValue')
```

And I get this error :

```
        {
      "error": {
        "message": "[essql] > Unexpected error from Elasticsearch: [unresolved_exception] Invalid call to nullable on an unresolved object ScalarSubquery[With[{}]
\\_Project[[?COUNT(?*)]]
\\_Filter[(status) REGEX (LikePattern)#5139]
 \\_UnresolvedRelation[[][index=monitoring-func-*],null,Unknown index [monitoring-func-*]],5142] AS ?"
      }
    }
```

Seeing *"unknown Index"*, I first thought that the wildcard was the problem.

But it's not, it's perfectly fine in my others Elasticsearch queries.

Is there something about the *Subqueries*, *the multiple SELECT*, that Elasticsearch SQL doesn't handle well ?
I didn't find any ressource or topics on this, but maybe I've searched the wrong way.

Comment: It seems there is not support for sub-queries on ES SQL

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Elasticsearch version, essql either doesn't support subqueries or it is very limited, here is the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-limitations.html#_using_a_sub_select).

Comment: Maybe you should give some explanation and/or sample code, along with the link you've posted.